# Settings for users on a new node or block

Tags: 7, users

I want that users be able to configure some settings on the site for different tasks as shown below.

[Checkbox] Recieve updates from site
[Checkbox] Notify by mail when i get userpoints //user points
[Checkbox] Notify by mail when i recieve a friend request /user relationships

and so on. the above should appear in a new node say node/settings and if a user clicks a check box then only he/she would be notified by mail, for instance.

Is it possible, How?

Appreciate any help because i am at odds